# How to populate dropdowns(2 or more depth level) with Category/Subcategory in Rails using the Ancestry gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have Rails 5.2.3 and I use the ancestry gem.

I want a user to create an offer for an automotive part, but in the new form, I want to be able to choose the category/subcategory that the part belongs to, and then to fill in the other details that I have, and then submit the form to create the offer. Let's say that someone wants to sell Brake Pads.

So first has to select the Category/Subcategory and so on...

(So when he choose Car, then the second dropdown should show the subcategories for the Car)

E.g:

Dropdown1: Car
Dropdown2: Brakes

So after choosing Brakes, he can fill in the other fields and submit.

**What I have:**

I have already created the Category/Subcategory in the console just to make it work:
Eg

```
car = Category.create!(name: "Car")
brakes = Category.create!(name: "Brakes", parent: car)
```

```
#category.rb
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_ancestry cache_depth: true
  has_many :parts
end
```

```
#part.rb
class Part < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
end
```

```
#categories_controller.rb
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def select_item
    category = @category.find(params[:category_id])
    render json: category.children
  end
end
```

```
#app/inputs/fake_select_input.rb
class FakeSelectInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::CollectionSelectInput
  def input(wrapper_options = nil)
    label_method, value_method = detect_collection_methods

    merged_input_options = 
    merge_wrapper_options(input_html_options, 
    wrapper_options).merge(input_options.slice(:multiple, 
    :include_blank, :disabled, :prompt))

    template.select_tag(
      attribute_name,
      template.options_from_collection_for_select(collection, 
      value_method, label_method, selected: 
      input_options[:selected], disabled: 
      input_options[:disabled]),
      merged_input_options
    )
  end
end
```

```
#routes.rb 
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :parts
  resources :categories, only: [] do
   get :select_item, on: :collection
  end
 end
```

```
#application.js
  $('#first-dropdown').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'categories/select_item?category_id=' + $(this).val(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      var childElement = $('#second-dropdown');
      childElement.html('');
      data.forEach(function(v) {
        var id = v.id;
        console.log(id);
        var name = v.name;
        childElement.append('<option value="' + id + '">' + name + '</option>');
      });
     }
   });
 });
```

```
#views/parts/new.html.haml
  = simple_form_for @part do |f|
    = f.input :parent_category_id, as: :fake_select, collection: Category.roots, input_html: { id: 'first-dropdown' }, label: "Category"
    = f.input :category_id, collection: [], input_html: { id: 'second-dropdown' }, label: "Subcategory"
    = f.input :title
    = f.input :part_number
    = f.input :price, label: "Price"
    = f.input :condition, label: "Condition", prompt: "-", collection:([["New", "New"], ["Used", "Used"], ["Rebuilt", "Rebuilt"], ["Aftermarket/Imitation", "Aftermarket/Imitation"]])
    = f.input :make, label: "Part Make"
    = f.input :part_model_name, label: "Part Model"
    = f.input :description
    .form-group
      = f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary btn-block"
```

**The thing is that the Dropdown1 has the Category "Car", and the Dropdown2 is always empty,** and ofc I have no errors (I am using ancestry because later I will add many categories / subcategories / subsubcategories etc)

The problem: [image of my dropdowns (When I open the second is empty)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctrFa.png)

Comment: Maybe instead of two select boxes, you could use just one, but with [option groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup)? That may be easier - not that you can't solve your current problem.

Comment: @taylorthurlow I did what you said and it works perfect, but the reason that I want separate dropdowns is that I want to extend the application and I will have many categories-subcategories-subsubcategories, so to use just one it's not that handy

Comment: Does the javascript log to the console successfully when you loop over the data? `console.log(id);`

Comment: Gotcha. So that's probably the best place to start looking. If you don't already know how to use a debugger in your javascript, [read this](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/). I'd use the debugger to check out what the value of `data` is in your `success` callback. The data should represent the list of category items that were sent as JSON by your `CategoriesController#select_item` action. The fact that there are no console logs means that the `data.forEach` isn't actually looping over any data.